# Bijectiveness, injectiveness and surjectiveness of Fourier transformation defined on $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n), p\in [1, 2]$

Tags: fourier-analysis

For Fourier transformation defined from $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $p\in [1, 2]$, and $1/p+1/q=1$,

I heard that when $p=2$, FT is bijective.

Is $p=2$ iff

- FT is bijective,
- FT is injective, or/and
- FT is surjective?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: All $L^p$ functions are tempered distributions, and the Fourier transform is an automorphism of the space of tempered distributions, so it's always injective.

Comment: Is the fourier transform well defined in the way you write it? Because On $L^1 (\mathbb{R})$ the Fourier transform is in $BC(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: What is $BUC(\mathbb R)$? The range of FT on $L^1(\mathbb R)$ is  $L^\infty(\mathbb R)$, isn't it?

Comment: @Tim Sorry it is Only $BC(\mathbb{R})$ those are the Bounded Continuous functions which are a subset of $L^\infty $ for sure, but for $p>1$ how do you know that the integral converges at all (over which the FT is defined?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: For $p \in [1,2]$,  $FT(L^p) \subseteq L^q$ with $1/p+1/q=2$, doesn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Fourier transform is always injective. In greatest generality, it's bijective as a map on the space of tempered distributions. Indeed, the transform of distribution $T$ is the distribution $\widehat T$ such that $\widehat{T}\varphi = T\widehat \varphi$ for all test functions $\varphi$ in the [Schwartz space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space). The Fourier transform is  a linear isomorphism of the Schwartz space onto itself. Therefore, $T\mapsto \widehat T$ is a bijection on the space of tempered distributions.

The Fourier transform is not surjective as a map $L^p\mapsto L^q$ for $1\le p<2$. When $p=1$, this follows from the fact that the Fourier transform of an integrable function is continuous. (Alternatively, from the fact that $L^1$ is separable by $L^\infty$ isn't.) For $1<p<2$ one can argue as follows: if $g\in L^q$ is a Fourier transform of $f\in L^p$, then $\widehat g\in L^p$ (because $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ is just $\mathcal F$ composed with a flip). Thus, if $\mathcal{F}:L^p\to L^q$ were surjective, it would follows that   $\mathcal F$   maps $L^q$ to $L^p$ when $q>2$. The latter is known to be false ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#On_Lp_spaces)).

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answer before that the Fourier transform $T : L^2 \rightarrow L^2$ is indeed surjective, the answer is: the Fourier transform is bijective iff $p=2$ (considering it on all $L^p, p \in [1,2]$).

The most important igredient to show this is Plancherel's Theorem (unitarity of $T$) which is first used to extend $T$ continuously from $L^1$ to $L^2$ and later to show invertibility of $T$ on all of $L^2$.