# $e^{-z^2}$ cannot be expressed as $\int_1^{-1} f(t)e^{itz}dt$ for some $f\in L^1[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration, entire-functions

Let $F(z) = e^{−z^2}$ . I am trying to prove that there is no $f \in L^1[−1, 1]$ such that
$F(z) =\int_1^{-1} f(t)e^{itz}dt$.

I first tried to show that $\int_1^{-1} f(t)e^{itz}dt$ is not an entire function of $z$ . But what I actually got is that $\int_1^{-1} f(t)e^{itz}dt$ is entire (by Morera's theorem). So I think I need a different approach, but I can't find such one. Any hints?

Comment: PS what you managed to prove is reminiscent of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley-Wiener_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a standard calculation (complete the square then use Cauchy's theorem to reduce to $z=0$) that
$$F(z)=\int_{\mathbb R} \frac1{2\sqrt \pi}e^{-t^2/4} e^{-itz} dt.$$
Since the Fourier transform is [injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446870/bijectiveness-injectiveness-and-surjectiveness-of-fourier-transformation-define), (WLOG switching $f(-t)$ for $f(t)$),
$$ F(z) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(t) \mathbb 1_{[-1,1]}(t) e^{-itz} dt$$
would imply that almost everywhere in $\mathbb R$,
$$\frac1{2\sqrt \pi}e^{-t^2/4}=f(t) \mathbb 1_{[-1,1]}(t),$$
which is immediately absurd for any $|t|\ge1$.